# Do like charges separating by a small distance release a photon?

Tags: photons, electrons

I believe from earlier physics that an electron moving from higher to a lower potential (e.g. higher energy state to a lower) can release a photon.

Given two like charges -- two electrons for example -- does moving them farther apart release a photon?

In aggregate, does decreasing the density of like charge on a conductor release photons?

I'm asking in the context of discharging a capacitor plate.  At a higher initial charge there is a greater potential from the electrons (on the negatively charged plate) being close together.  As the capacitor discharges, the negative charge reduces in density, which I think would correspond to a lower potential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given two like charges -- two electrons for example -- does moving them farther apart release a photon?

Photons are released when charged particles are accelerated. . Moving them apart may generate photons if there is acceleration. If the velocity is constant, no radiation.

Electrons  in [conduction band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conduction_band)s of metals are in a quantum mechanical state and any energy they lose in electromagnetic radiation going from one level to another is very small as the conduction band is practically a continuum of eigenstates of the lattice. So there is no radiation from discharging a capacitor.

The potential difference is a collective effect of the motion of electrons,the kinetic energy of the ones who leave diminishes the energy looked at in the atomic level. The potential of the circuit is an emergent value from the collective behavior combined with the charge  of the electrons.